# python - Run indented code through keyboard shortcuts in Spyder as in RStudio

Tags: python, r, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

I would like to be able to run an indented block of code in python in the same way I do in R. In particular, if in RStudio I have the following indented block of code:

```
print(seq(from = 1,
          to = 10,
          by = 1))
```

I can place the cursor everywhere (at the beginning of the code, in the middle, at the end) except in a new line below and simply press Cmd+Enter (or Ctrl+Enter) and I can run such code.

However, in Spyder 4.2, a similar code like this one:

```py
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda', 'Ford','Audi'],
        'Price': [20000, 30000, 40000]}
```

will not run wherever I place the cursor, and I have to select the two lines to create the dataframe and launch the whole selection with Cmd+Enter (I modified the keyboard shortcuts in the preferences of Spyder to run a selection).

Any advice on how to run such code without selecting it first? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You said

> Any advice on how to run such code without selecting it first?

Yes, you need to use cells for that. You can create a cell by inserting a comment that starts with `# %%`, like this

```
import pandas as pd

# %%
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda', 'Ford','Audi'],
        'Price': [20000, 30000, 40000]}
```

That will allow you to run the piece of code enclosed by those comments with the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (run current cell and advance to the next one); or <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (run current cell and stay on it).

If that explanation was not clear enough, you can learn more about cells in [our docs](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/editor.html#defining-code-cells).

Comment: No problem. Glad you find it useful.